# Add tooltip on hover to node in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map which people can draw and modify geometries on. For Polygons and LineStrings you are able to delete the individual nodes by holding down <kbd>alt</kbd> and clicking the node, but this is not obvious to the user without further instruction.

I want to be able to add a tooltip when a user hovers over a node telling them that they can do this, but I can't figure out the exact steps to do it.

Take the following code, modified from the [Draw and Modify](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html) and [Custom Polygon Styles](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html) examples (working code sandbox below)

```
const raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

const source = new VectorSource();
const vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: [
    new Style({
      fill: new Fill({
        color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)"
      }),
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: "#ffcc33",
        width: 2
      }),
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: "#ffcc33"
        })
      })
    }),
    new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: "orange"
        })
      }),
      geometry: function (feature) {
        // return the coordinates of the first ring of the polygon
        const coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
        return new MultiPoint(coordinates);
      }
    })
  ]
});

// Limit multi-world panning to one world east and west of the real world.
// Geometry coordinates have to be within that range.
const map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});

const modify = new Modify({
  source: source
});
map.addInteraction(modify);

let draw, snap; // global so we can remove them later
const typeSelect = document.getElementById("type");

function addInteractions() {
  draw = new Draw({
    source: source,
    type: typeSelect.value
  });
  map.addInteraction(draw);
  // snap = new Snap({ source: source });
  // map.addInteraction(snap);
}

addInteractions();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-cl85wd?file=/main.js:1860-1975

This uses a custom polygon style to show the nodes, what I would like is, when you hover over the node it comes up with a small tooltip alongside it telling the user how to delete the node.

I feel this could be done one of two ways, but both I am stuck on a particular part.

Option 1: Add it to the style. You can add 'text' to the style used to render the nodes, but this will apply always and I can't see a way of only making it apply when the individual node is hovered.

Option 2: Add a 'pointerMove' event and detect when you are hovering a node, then show a tooltip next to the mouse (much like how the [measure example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html) has a tooltip next to the mouse). I can detect when a feature is hovered over, but not whether the user is hovering over a node (and in range for the Alt Click deletion to work)

Comment: See this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html  Replace "drag to modify" with "click to delete" or similar.

Comment: So very close - https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-cl85wd?file=/main.js - But ideally I only want the node that I am actually hovering over to have the tooltip, not every node

Comment: You can test inside the modify style function if the modify point is on a polygon vertex and update the style accordingly https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-m94exe?file=/main.js

Comment: Yes that's perfect! Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I did make a very slight change, adding a coordinate length test and only showing the tooltip if there are more than 4 coordinates (not a triangle), since the node deletion does not delete nodes when there are only 4 coordinates - https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-cnkuqz?file=/main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking Mikes suggestions in the comments, I ended up with a solution where the the help text would appear on hover of a node and only is there were more than 3 coordinates in the polygon (any less and you can't delete a node, as it would then no longer be a valid polygon.

The relevant code is here

```
modify.getOverlay().setStyle(function (feature) {
  const coordinate = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  let style = defaultEditingStyleFunction;
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate), function (
    feature
  ) {
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    if (geometry.getType() === "Polygon") {
      const coordinates = geometry
        .getCoordinates()[0]
        .map(function (coordinate) {
          return coordinate.toString();
        });
      if (
        coordinates.length > 4 &&
        coordinates.includes(coordinate.toString())
      ) {
        style = function () {
          return vertexStyle;
        };
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
  return style(feature);
});
```

[Full codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/draw-and-modify-features-forked-cnkuqz?file=%2Fmain.js%3A1%2C1)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
var tooltipOverlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: tooltip,
  offset: [10, 0],
  positioning: 'bottom-left'
});
map.addOverlay(tooltipOverlay);

map.on('pointermove',function(e){
  if( source.getFeatures().length ){
    let v = false;
    source.getFeatures().forEach(f=>{
      if( f.getGeometry().getType() !== 'Point' ){
        let coords = f.getGeometry().getType() == 'LineString'?f.getGeometry().getCoordinates():f.getGeometry().getLinearRing().getCoordinates();
        coords.forEach(c=>{
          let p2 = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(c);
          var dx = e.pixel[0] - p2[0];
          var dy = e.pixel[1] - p2[1];        
          if( (Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)) < 8 ){
            v = true;
          }
        })
      }
    })
    if( v ){
      tooltip.style.display = '';
      tooltip.innerHTML = 'Alt+click - delete vertex!';
      tooltipOverlay.setPosition(e.coordinate);
    }else{
      tooltip.style.display = 'none';
      tooltip.innerHTML = '';
      tooltipOverlay.setPosition(undefined);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for posting an answer! Could you please elaborate on how your code answers the question? As it stands, you provided a snippet that doesn't compile without any explanation as to how it helps the author, so it's difficult for others to know whether your solution works or not.